# When I find the max value in an array how do I find out which order it was in?

Tags: php, arrays

Basically I need to find the highest value in an array of numbers and then which order that was in. Say the array was (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4) I would need it to return 5, and what order 5 was in.  In this case it would be in 5th place out of 9 values.

I've been finding the max via this method:

```
$value = array(1,2,3,4,5,7,6,1,4,1,3);
$value = max($freq);
```

In this case I would need the values 7 and 6 (the place in the array) to be logged.

Comment: `$freq = array(1,2,3,4,5,7,6,1,4,1,3);
$value = max($freq); $pos = array_search($value, $freq);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given**

```
$freq = array(1,2,3,4,5,7,6,1,4,1,3);
$value = max($freq);
```

**This**

```
$position = array_keys(array_values($freq), [$value]);
```

**Results in**

```
array(5)
```

This means, the value has been found at the sixths position (you know, we start counting at 0). It's an array because the maximum value might be at several positions and you probably want to know all of them. Otherwise, use `array_search($value, array_values($freq))` instead, this will give you the position of the first occurance.

I used `array_values()` to normalize the array keys, feel free to leave it out if you need the actual key or your arrays always have incrementing numerical keys starting at 0.

---

### Reference

**[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)**

> ```
> array array_keys ( array $array [, mixed $search_value [, bool $strict = false ]] )
> ```
>
> array_keys() returns the keys, numeric and string, from the array.
>
> If the optional search_value is specified, then only the keys for that
>   value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are
>   returned.

**[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)**

> ```
> array array_values ( array $array )
> ```
>
> array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the
>   array numerically.